# how to get the first value and the last three values of a certain group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Currently, I have a time series data table and I have to get the first and the last entry for each group .So I am using the below code to do that .

```
data[,c(.SD[1,] , .SD[2,]),by=c("id","status","group")]
```

Now instead of the first and last, I want to take the first and the last three entries by the grouping.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Why the title and body of question do not match?

Answer (score 4):

quick and dirty

```
#sample data
DT <- data.table( id = 1:2, value = 1:100 )
#code
DT[, .SD[ c( 1:3, .N-2, .N-1, .N ) ], by = .(id) ]

#output
#    id value
# 1:  1     1
# 2:  1     3
# 3:  1     5
# 4:  1    95
# 5:  1    97
# 6:  1    99
# 7:  2     2
# 8:  2     4
# 9:  2     6
# 10: 2    96
# 11: 2    98
# 12: 2   100
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `head` and `tail` will be safer and using unique once on the indices as mentioned by sindri_baldur:

```
k <- 3L
DT[unique(DT[, c(head(.I, k), tail(.I, k)), id]$V1)]
```

output:

```
    id VAL
 1:  1   1
 2:  1   2
 3:  1   3
 4:  1   5
 5:  1   6
 6:  1   7
 7:  2   8
 8:  2   9
 9:  2  10
10:  2  11
11:  2  12
12:  2  13
13:  3  14
14:  3  15
15:  3  16
16:  3  17
17:  3  18
18:  4  19
19:  4  20
20:  4  21
21:  4  22
22:  5  23
23:  5  24
24:  5  25
25:  6  26
26:  6  27
27:  7  28
    id VAL
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
x <- sort(sequence(7:1))
DT <- data.table(id=x, VAL=1:length(x))
```

Comment: I was thinking of `rbind(df[, head(.SD, 2), .(id,status,group)], 
      df[, tail(.SD, 2), .(id,status,group)])`.

Comment: What about `DT[unique(DT[, c(first(.I, 3L), last(.I, 3L)), id]$V1)]`, using data.table's first() and last(), and applying unique() only once.

Answer (score 1):

Using @chinsoon12's data, here is another way:

```
k = 3L
max_grp = 2L * k

init_seq = seq_len(k)
k_minus_one = k - 1L

DT[DT[, if (.N <=max_grp) .I else .I[c(init_seq, (.N-k_minus_one):.N)], by = x]$V1]
```

This answer scales well but is definitely an eyesore.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `dplyr` could be

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id, status, group) %>% 
  slice(c(1:3, (n()-2):n()))
```

---

#### Example with the `iris` dataset

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(c(1:3, (n()-2):n()))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
#  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    
#  4          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#  5          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#  6          5           3.3          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#  7          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#  8          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#  9          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
# 10          6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
# 11          5.1         2.5          3           1.1 versicolor
# 12          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
# 13          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
# 14          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica 
# 15          7.1         3            5.9         2.1 virginica 
# 16          6.5         3            5.2         2   virginica 
# 17          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 
# 18          5.9         3            5.1         1.8 virginica
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `dplyr::filter` solution to taking 1st 3 and last 3 entries within each group:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id, status, group) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1:3, (n()-2):n()))
```